# Mulesoft service as an executable Jar

Tags: jenkins, automation, devops, mulesoft

At the moment I am working on the **automation** of a Mule service let's call it service1 that receives data through rest and transforms it in a different format before sending it to the next service

1. Jenkins to pick up the service 1 Jar from Artifactory;
2. Spin it on the fly with a test profile (Jenkins can spin a new JVM);
3. run the BDD tests;
4. destroy the instance;

**Is this possible since Mule 4 is on a clustered environment?**

Comment: Mule 3 or Mule 4?

Comment: It's Mule 4. I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Mule 4 can not be executed as an executable jar. Think of it as a service, for example a database service. You will need to start an instance of it to do the testing. What you will be testing is not Mule but your Mule applications deployed into it. If you use Runtime Manager you may use Runtime Manager APIs to deploy the applications to be tested. Note that if you need to test the applications in a cluster you need to start more than one node.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am aware that I am testing mule, in fact I was talking about a Mule service not Mule itself.